# elegant way to do inverse matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra, tensorflow2.0

I would like to invert a bunch of tensors in a list using cholesky decomposition in tensorflow 2, but the resulting code is quite ugly. is there any elegant / more pythonic way to do something like this :

```
iMps = []
for Mp in Mps :
    cholMp  = tf.linalg.cholesky(Mp)
    icholMp = tf.linalg.inv(cholMp)
    iMp = tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(icholMp),icholMp)
    iMps.append(iMp)
```

is it possible to replace for loop with other stuff ?, Mps is list of tensors with different size (can i represent it as something else?). is there any way to make it more elegant ?

Comment: Not so ugly.  Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, I guess.  You could write a function for the loop operation and execute it as a lambda over the collection of Mps.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using python Map function.

I have modified your code to create Map function like below.

```
def inverse_tensors(Mp):
    cholMp  = tf.linalg.cholesky(Mp)
    icholMp = tf.linalg.inv(cholMp)
    iMp = tf.tensordot(tf.transpose(icholMp),icholMp,axes=0)
    return iMp 

iMps = list(map(inverse_tensors,list_tensors))
```

Hope this answers your question, Happy Learning!